# DB design/scalability - new "Type IDs" with potentially variable number of required columns

Tags: database-design, scalability

I am designing the database of an application that will manage assets owned by my company. Say that I've got the following tables:

```
+-----------------+
| Component Type  |
+-----------------+--------------------------+
| ComponentTypeID | ComponentTypeDescription |
+-----------------+--------------------------+
| 1               | Server                   |
| 2               | PC                       |
| 3               | Database                 |
+-----------------+--------------------------+

+-----------+
| Component |
+-----------------+---------------+
| ComponentTypeID | ComponentName |
+-----------------+---------------+
| 1               | Server1       |
| 1               | Server2       |
| 2               | PC1           |
| 3               | Database1     |
| 3               | Database2     |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

I am looking to store all components in the "Component" Table. There are extra details that are required for each ComponentTypeID, but the details will vary for each one. For example, Server and PC will both have "Operating System" and Database will have "DBMS".

To the best of my knowledge, it is bad practice to have columns in a table that are filled with nulls. For example:

```
+-----------+
| Component |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+------------+
| ComponentTypeID | ComponentName | OperatingSystem     | DBMS       |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+------------+
| 1               | Server1       | Windows Server 2012 | (null)     |
| 1               | Server2       | Windows Server 2012 | (null)     |
| 2               | PC1           | Windows 10          | (null)     |
| 3               | Database1     | (null)              | SQL Server |
| 3               | Database2     | (null)              | MySQL      |
+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+------------+
```

I also know that it is bad practice to multi-purpose a single column. For example:

```
+-----------+
| Component |
+-----------------+---------------+----------------------+
| ComponentTypeID | ComponentName | OperatingSystem/DBMS |
+-----------------+---------------+----------------------+
| 1               | Server1       | Windows Server 2012  |
| 1               | Server2       | Windows Server 2012  |
| 2               | PC1           | Windows 10           |
| 3               | Database1     | SQL Server           |
| 3               | Database2     | MySQL                |
+-----------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

What is a good way to handle this issue? If I want to allow my users to add ComponentTypes to the ComponentType table, what do I need to consider in the future?